# Selenium cannot locate an element

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using `Selenium` for download some data from the site, in particular this is the [url](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/usa/mls/chicago-fire-new-york-city-CAl0LCJs/?r=1#ah;2).

As you can see there are two tabs:

- Full Time
- 1st Half

[image]

I'm trying to access to the `1st Half` content by simulating a click on it through `Selenium`, this is my code:

```
var chromeOpts = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOpts.AddArguments("headless");
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOpts);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);            
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(new Uri("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/usa/mls/chicago-fire-new-york-city-CAl0LCJs/?r=1#ah;2"));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'1st') and contains(text(),'Half')]")).Click();
string html = driver.PageSource;
```

the problem is that I get this error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 'element not visible

I though that my `XPath` is wrong, but I tried with other tabs and works, also the `html` structure is correct.

What's happening?

Comment: Can you link to the website, so I can have a look at it

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sleep timer just be completely sure that the page indeed has fully loaded before you go ahead an search for the element?

Comment: It's not throwing any such error, it works very fine. You don't even need implicit wait before you click that tab because the required element is completely ready even before page completely loads.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen the url is in the question already, I tried to increase the waiting time and same issue.

Comment: @Rajagopalan sorry but I don't understand, my code doesn't work for me, and each time I post a `Selenium` question related, you said that for you working, this not help me very much, how is possible that my code doesn't works for me and works instead for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the unique ID `bettype-tabs-scope`, and there is `ul` and 3 `li` elements.

```html
<div id="bettype-tabs-scope" class="tab-nav-detail">
  <ul class="sub-menu subactive" style="display: block;">
    <li class=" active"><span class="topleft_corner"></span><span class="topright_corner"></span><strong><span>Full&nbsp;Time</span></strong></li>
    <li class=""><a onmousedown="uid(28)._onClick();return false;" title="1st&nbsp;Half" href=""><span>1st&nbsp;Half</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a onmousedown="uid(29)._onClick();return false;" title="2nd&nbsp;Half" href=""><span>2nd&nbsp;Half</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can pretty easily do:

```
//Find the unique element and the get all children list items.
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("bettype-tabs-scope")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
//Click the list items that has "1st Half" as it's text.
listItems.Where(li => li.Text == "1st Half").Single().Click();
```

Otherwise, you can also do `driver.FindElement(By.Id("bettype-tabs-scope")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"))[1].Click();` if you are certain that the "1st half" button will always be second in the results (first being the Full Time).

Answer (score 0):

It should work as it works fine on my machine. Maybe page load is taking time on your machine. You can use expected condition wait for checking the visibility of the element. Make sure you've installed both the Selenium. Webdriver and Selenium.Support NuGet packages for your project. You'll need the Selenium. Support package to use ExpectedConditions.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'1st') and contains(text(),'Half')]")));
element.Click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements are found with same xpath and the first element is invisible. In your code, you have used the `FindElement` method and hence it is finding the invisible element returning an error.

**Solution:**
You can perform the click action in two ways.

**Option 1:**

Change the Xpath as `//*[contains(text(),'1st') and contains(text(),'Half')][1]`

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'1st') and contains(text(),'Half')][1]")).Click();
```

**Option 2:**

Find all the matched elements using `FindElements` method and then perform the click action only, If the particular element is disaplyed

```
var halfElementList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'1st') and contains(text(),'Half')]"));

string html = "";
foreach(var element in halfElementList)
{
    if (element.Displayed)
    {
        element.Click();
        html = driver.PageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: none of the above solution worked for me, the strange thing is that this issue happening only when I try to click on `1st Half` of the main tab (specified in the question)

Comment: oh. Both the options are working perfectly for me. What error you are getting it?